# Construct a std::mem_fn by type

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

Consider this contrived example:

```
template<typename Fn, typename Iter, typename T>
void funny_transform(Iter first, Iter last, vector<T>& v)
{
    transform(first, last,
              back_inserter(v),
              Fn());
}
```

Normally we would pass in the functor object directly, but this example is contrived to simulate the behavior of many STL containers. For example, `std::map` can take the *type* of the comparator and default-construct it, instead of taking a comparator object directly. (My actual use case is with some stateless functor class. Since the class is stateless, I can only pass in types.)

The problem is with `std::mem_fn`. If I try to do something like:

```
auto get_size = mem_fn(&string::size);

vector<string> v1 = { ... };
vector<string::size_type> v2;

funny_transform<decltype(get_size)>(v1.cbegin(), v1.cend(), v2);  // oops
```

This won't work, because `decltype(get_size)` (whatever it is) does not have a default constructor. Though strangely it has copy and move constructors. Switching to a simple lambda won't work either, for exactly the same reason.

Do I have to write my own functor `struct` to work around this problem? Is there any standard library tool that I can use?

Comment: "std::map takes the type of the comparator, instead of a comparator object. " Wat?

Comment: And the thing `mem_fn` returns is not stateless by definition.

Comment: @T.C. I should've said "`std::map` can take the type of the comparator and  try to default-construct it."

Comment: @T.C. Why is it not stateless? I think a purely stateless functor `struct` can be used to implement it. I could be wrong though.

Comment: Why don't you try writing it?

Comment: @T.C Oh now I see why. Pointers to different member functions can have the same type.

Comment: Even c++14 generic stateless lambda's default ctor gets deleted. It seems you need to define your own functor. This could do http://ideone.com/ErYxeZ

Comment: This is easier in C++17 with `auto` template value arguments.  `my_mem_fun<&string::size>`.

Comment: Also note that it's forbidden to take the address of standard library member functions.

Comment: @T.C. Didn't know that! Can you point me to where the standard says this?

Comment: http://eel.is/c++draft/member.functions#2. Implementations are allowed to mutilate their signatures as they see fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
template<class F>
F& magic_store(F* f) {
  static const F r=std::move(*f);
  return r;
}
template<class F>
struct stateless_t{
  stateless_t(F&&f){ magic_store<F>(&f); }
  stateless_t()=default;

  template<class...Args>
  decltype(auto) operator()(Args&&...args)const{
    return magic_store<F>(nullptr)(std::forward<F>(f));
  }
};
template<class F>
stateless_t<F> make_stateless(F f){ return std::move(f); }
```

Now you can do

```
auto get_size = make_stateless([](auto&s){return s.size();});

vector<string> v1 = { ... };
vector<string::size_type> v2;

funny_transform<decltype(get_size)>(v1.cbegin(), v1.cend(), v2);  // works
```

Note that this is a horrible hack, but standard legal.  It is easily abused and easy to screw up non-locally.  Only use it with a lambda that is already stateless.  Never *anything* else.

---

In C++17 you could write:

```
template<auto F>
struct stateless_invoker{
  template<class...Args>
  decltype(auto) operator()(Args&&...args) const{
    return std::invoke( F, std::forward<Args>(args)... );
  }
};
```

which gives you:

```
using get_size = stateless_invoker<&std::string::size>;

vector<string> v1 = { ... };
vector<string::size_type> v2;

funny_transform<get_size>(v1.cbegin(), v1.cend(), v2);  // works
```

which is less hacky.  This can be reproduced in C++11 but is ugly.

Comment: @ziz check out the C++17 version, which is not nearly as evil.

Comment: Hmm the C++17 version looks much more reasonable. Can any type bind to the `auto F`? Does it have the same constraints as current non-type template parameters?

Comment: @ziz it is sort of like `template<class T, T t>` but just `template<auto t>`.  If it has further quirks, I would not know, I have not used it yet.  ;)

Comment: Do you know if there is a compiler able to actually compile this? I tried gcc 6.1.0 with `-std=c++1z` but gcc couldn't recognize the syntax.

Comment: @ziz nope.  See http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0127r1.html for the (accepted to feature complete draft) proposal I based the C++17 version off of.

Comment: Thanks! I've added some update to the question based on your idea; can you take a look to see if there are any caveats?

Comment: @ziz write answers as answers, do not edit it into the question.

Comment: I think it should be possible to check if it is stateless via `std::is_empty`, `std::is_pointer` and `std::is_member_pointer`

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Yakk 's idea, a simple workaround in C++14 can look something like this:

```
template<typename PMF, PMF pmf>
struct my_mem_fn_t {
    template<typename... Args>
    constexpr decltype(auto) operator()(Args&&... args) const
        noexcept(noexcept(std::mem_fn(pmf)(std::forward<Args>(args)...)))
    {
        return std::mem_fn(pmf)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};

// well, if you really want to use macro
#define my_mem_fn(pmf) my_mem_fn_t<decltype(pmf), pmf>()
```

Then:

```
auto get_size = my_mem_fn_t<decltype(&string::size), &string::size>;
//          or: my_mem_fn(&string::size);

string s("hello");
cout << decltype(get_size)()(s) << '\n';  // prints 5
```